# ASP.NET Server Controls - Data Source

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I put a dropdownlist on a webform and give a list as datasource.
But what can I do, if I want the first item in dropdownlist to be "Select a user" or something like that?

For example: // ddlAllUsers is a DropDownList

```
        List<REGUSER> users = UserOperations.GetAllUsers();
        ddlAllUsers.DataSource = users;
        ddlAllUsers.DataTextField = "NameLastName";
        ddlAllUsers.DataValueField = "ID";
        ddlAllUsers.DataBind();
```

Adding a new item in list whose associated property is "Select a user" is a solution, but I don't prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually add an item to your List with required properties.

For example,

```
List<REGUSER> users = UserOperations.GetAllUsers();
users.Insert( 0, new REGUSER() { NameLastName = "Select a user...", ID = -1 } );
```